# Drush 8.1 Drupal 8 throws PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] on MAMP

Tags: 8, drush

After installing Drupal 8 (via installation wizard), trying to run any drush command, getting below error:

```
drush en views_ui
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php on line 79 Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Drupal version: 8.2.x

Drush version:  8.1-dev

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your database host setting is 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: This is a DB connection issue. I faced this  while DB server was down. Before replacing 'localhost', better check your DB connection is working

Comment: Also, it is worth to check file permissions since I didn't check the symlink I had used and the original file used `r-xr-xr-x` (555). Changed to `755` and this error was fixed. Would be nice if a better, more specific error would be logged by Drupal.